# textbox becomes disabled (not editable) in debug mode in visual studio 2005

Tags: debugging, textbox, visual-studio-2005, disabled-input

It has been working fine with no any issue, just suddenly noticed I can't edit any textbox if I am in debug mode, no problem in run mode
My visual studio is 2005, never had this problem before.

Comment: The issue was gone after I upgrade IE to 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was gone after I upgrade IE to 8